# wrong Chinese characters in android coding related

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a chinese string:

```
String t = "中文..."
```

Now I want to display it in some text view:

```
TextView tv = findViewById(id)
tv.setText(t, null);
```

But this is showing wrong characters... any idea how could I show it
correctly?

Well, I am asked to post the real code, actually the above code is almost the
real code:

```
suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
suggestions.add("今日");
```

Then I get suggestion first element and assign to t:

```
tv.setText(t, null);
```

BTW, when I log it out, I also see wrong characters...

Comment: Please, mention the output what you are getting.

Comment: The output is unrecognizable characters

Comment: did you have this error in `LogCat`? what does the `id` contain?

Comment: id is just the id for that text view. I think this must be the problem of encoding. I don't know how to specify that the string should be using UTF-8

Comment: encoding is not the problem...I have just tried with your chinese string and its output absolutely correct. Please, post your real code.

Comment: Could it be some config problem?

Comment: also post the `LogCat`.

Comment: Mylog(23647): ËØ∑ÂêëÁ•ûÂÖΩËÜúÊãú9‰∏ã ÂøÉ‰∏≠ÈªòÂøµÈÖçÂÅ∂ÂßìÂêç9Ê¨°„ÄÇ

Answer (score 0):

I remember writing strings in Japanese and getting the same problem. I didn't solve it, but have you tried using String resources? If you put Chinese characters in `res/values/strings.xml` instead of in your source code, they should display as expected.

You can access the Strings in your resource file like so:

```
String suggestion1 = context.getString(R.string.suggestion1);
```

To get an array of strings, like in your example, it's convenient to use string-arrays.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="suggestions">
         <item>示唆1</item>
         <item>示唆2</item>
         <item>示唆3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And then load them using:

```
String[] suggestions = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.suggestions);
```

Comment: Yeah, actually I have some strings in res/values/strings.xml and they could be displayed correctly. But I need to put these strings in the source code so I can loop through them... Is there a way to get the strings from res/values/strings.xml in the java code?

Comment: Yes, there are two things you can do. I will update the answer.